# Can we exclude hooking to specific applications in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I'm using `SetWindowsHookEx` to install global hooks from my application and get notifications via callback.

```
hook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(hookType, lpfn, hDll, 0);
```

Here `hookType` is `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_GETMESSAGE`. Everything works fine and the hook works perfect. However, few applications (Symantec AntiVirus to be specific) are throwing exceptions while injecting the dll.

Exception snippet from eventviewer

```
Faulting application name: ccSvcHst.exe, version: 12.12.3.14, time stamp: 0x58f54ea1
Faulting module name: ccL120U.dll, version: 12.12.3.14, time stamp: 0x58f55540
Exception code: 0xc0000005
```

After going through the MSDN documentation for the API, I could not find any help in excluding specific application list is possible or not.

Is there a way to prevent hooking to a pre-defined set of applications? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not really that surprising that antivirus tools resist being hooked.

Comment: Not sure if this works for `SetWindowsHookEx`, but you could try having your hook DLL's entry point function retrieve the name of the process the DLL is being loaded into in reply to `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, and for select processes return FALSE to abort the load.

Comment: *"applications [...] are throwing exceptions while injecting the dll"* - What exception? In which process?

Comment: @JonathanPotter maybe. Interestigly, this got fixed with the latest Symantec Update. It doesn't complain anymore

Comment: @IInspectable I edited the post to include the exception details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good suggestion. I'm already doing this for few of my own processes and haven't tried for this exe. Will check this